# Add texture to part of 3d object and then output whole object

Tags: texturing, objects

I have .obj file of truck where I want to assign a texture to tires. I am doing this in blender:

select the vertices/faces of tires
split it into different object (using P)
assign a texture file to the new object
combine the new object back to the main object using Ctrl+J
The problem is the texture file is not preserved and the whole model is assigned one of the texture files. How can I assign the texture to just tires?
[image: selecting tyre and splitting into separate object]
[image: output after merging the two objects]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you object has two materials like this:

[image]

you can select the second material, then in edit mode select your vertices where you want to assign the second material. Then press "Assign", so you give these selected vertices the new material.

```
Note: You don't have to separate the objects before.
```